# Dealing with URL phishing attempts

Tags: php, security, url, phishing, honeypot

Been looking at the usage statistics for my website, and I keep seeing tons of attempts to access WordPress, Joomla, blogs, feeds, asp files, etc. The funny part is I do not have any of that stuff on my site, and after seeing these logs will never use them. Currently, the phishing attempts are around 30% of my site's total page hits, so I am wanting to do something about it. For almost a decade now I have used a honeypot and so I am going to start redirecting known phishing attempts to a honeypot. And maybe try to track some of the worst-offending IP addresses, and blacklist them.

To do this I figure I need a list of all the URL's that I am seeing that are not found on my site. I could create a list manually, and that would be a very long and tedious process. But if I had to guess, I'd bet someone has already done this and likely keeps it up-to-date, so why reinvent the wheel.

So is there someone who maintains a list of URL's I can use/download to detect these phishing attempts?

EDIT - Answering M A SIDDIQUI comment.

No matter what URL is used on my site you will never get a 404 error. All pages are technically created in the index.php file. My system grabs everything after the first slash (/), sanitizes it, and then parses it to determine what gets loaded. And if the page does not exist they go straight to the home page. As such all URL's are valid, to make them not valid I have to find or create a list.

I had originally thought to just redirect all non-valid URLs but there is 2 issues with that. First, while looking at the usage statistics I did see URL's that I am fairly certain where typo's. Second, The previous version of the website used some different URL's than the current version. I originally had those redirected but as I haven't seen any traffic on them in a few years, so I no longer redirect them, but I would bet a few old links are still around. All that to say, I don't want to dump real users into a honeypot. In fact I would err on the side of caution and let some URL's go over risk it being a real person.

Comment: Create 404 page and in the page redirect honeypot.. Just an idea am not sure

Comment: How is that phishing? Isn’t this just a way to find exploitable files? Given certain exploits, phishing could very well be one of the attacker’s goals, but it’s one of possibly many.

Comment: I used the term as while I was searching for an answer that was the term used by others. I saw it here in SO, as well as some blogs, and elsewhere. And really, they are "fishing" for a software package to exploit. Not that they will ever find one.